# How to display date in exact format with month and year format

Tags: java, android, date

Hi how to display given string with `July  3, 1969` for string `1969-07-03`

```
String a="1969-07-03";
```

Expected output: `July 3, 1969`

I used this method initially to convert it to the right format.

```
  textView.setText(reverseIt(a)); // but this reverse the whole string.

    public static String reverseIt(String source) {
        int i, len = source.length();
        StringBuffer dest = new StringBuffer(len);

        for (i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i--)
          dest.append(source.charAt(i));
        return dest.toString();
      }
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Something like `SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.getDefault())`

You'll have to convert that string representation of a date to a `Date` object like:

```
public static Date getDate(String dateString) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    try {
        return df.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then use `String formattedDate = output.format(getDate(input))` (but of course handle the parse exception and potential null value)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this...
See if the string is `1969-07-03` and you want output `July  3, 1969`

Pseudocode:

```
int Year = First 4 chars //First break the string into three integers.
int month = 6-7 char
int date = 9-10 char

and then you can do something like

if(month==1){
    string monthname=January}
else if(month==2){string monthname= Feburary}....and so on....

and then print "monthname date, year"
```

Comment: And why should he create a functionality that already exists? (`SimpleDateFormat`)